# dt1 to hgt conversion

Tags: dted, hgt

I have an application that generally uses .hgt files for 3-arc-second resolution of elevation data. A military user has asked us to use .dt1 files (also 3-arc-second resolution) that they have furnished to us for a portion of our terrain.  Apparently, their data has "smoothed out" some elevation points to reflect the presence of human-created features like airfields.

Is there a utility that converts .dt1 to .hgt -- preferably that can run on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) (isn't it always) using [translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html). Below is close

```
gdal_translate -of SRTMHGT input.dt1 output.hgt
```

You will find limitations on both these formats though so read up. Here are you [binaries](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries).